# Reference needed for lower bound on number of guards in three-dimensional art gallery guarding

Tags: reference-request, computational-geometry, polytope

During my research (writing my master's thesis) I've stumbled across the book [*Art Gallery Theorems and Algorithms* by O’Rourke](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/ArtGalleryTheorems/art.html).
In chapter 10 (pdf available on the above site), section 10.2.2. he shows a lower bound of $\Omega\left(n^{3/2}\right)$ on the number of guards needed in three-dimensional art gallery guarding. He says (bold marking is by myself):

> In fact, we describe in this section a polyhedron **constructed by Seidel** that has these two properties.

I believe that the construction, as presented in the book, is not fully correct and thus I tried to find the original work by Seidel.
Sadly there is no reference in this section and the only reference in the book with Seidel is [*Constructing Arrangements of Lines and Hyperplanes with Applications* by H. Edelsbrunner, J. O’Rourke, and R. Seidel](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0215024) which does not include the construction.

I have looked through Seidels Google Scholar page but there seems to be nothing relevant.

- Do you have a source or know anything more about this construction?
- What could be a good and accepted way for me to obtain information? Contacting either of the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, Seidel's construction has only been published in O'Rourke's book and nowhere else.

In one of his papers, Seidel even refers to O'Rourke's book for a description of his own construction. He writes on top of page 253 of his joint paper with Jim Ruppert: 
**"In his book [9, p. 255] O'Rourke describes n-vertex three-dimensional polyhedra that require $\Omega(n^{3/2})$ guards."**

> Jim Ruppert, Raimund Seidel: On the Difficulty of Triangulating Three-Dimensional Nonconvex Polyhedra. Discrete & Computational Geometry 7: 227-253 (1992)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I had skimmed the paper you mentioned but not noticed the reference.Then the mention in O'Rourke's book seems to be the only one. I'll leave this question open for a day or two; if nothing else appears I will accept this as the answer.